# Does proving over the rational field extend to the real field

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

It is given that $x^{T}Ax\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$. This implies that the same is true for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$. Can this further extend to all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

It does not appear to be true to me since any irrational number can be expressed as the convex combination of two integer or rational numbers ($x=\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2$) and that would lead to terms of the kind $x_1^{T}Ax_2$ which could be negative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Is $x^TAx$ a continuous function of $x$?

Comment: So if $x^TAx$ dips into the negative side at some point, then at a nearby rational point...

Comment: I get it I guess. Since the function is continuous an irrational point at which the function is negative would imply that it is also negative at a nearby rational point giving a contradiction.

Comment: Correct. Another way (if you have done a bit topology) would be to use the observation that by continuity the set $U$ of points $x$ where $x^TAx<0$ is open. But a non-empty open set always contains an open ball, and any open ball contains a rational point contradicting what you already knew.